# Browser Cross Domain issue in Infor M3 / IOS (Infor Operating System)

Tags: typescript, browser, content-security-policy

I have an application I've written using the M3 TypeScript SDK for H5 *(The M3 web client)*.  The program is being run in M3/H5 in Chrome on Windows.  It's for processing a credit card payment, and accesses the processor's site in an iFrame inside M3/H5.  It passes messages back to M3/H5 using dispatchEvent.  The hosting domain and the serving domain are the same.

The form, iFrame, and dialog are dynamically built using TypeScript, and add the appropriate CSC headers to them when generated.  Adding the CSC header frame-ancestors **solved** any issues with Cross-Domain errors I had during development **when running in the M3 BE directly**.

However, when I open M3 in IOS *(Infor Operating System)*, I get the error *"Blocked a frame with origin [x] from accessing a cross-orgin frame."*, even with the headers added.  I've tried adding https:// to the domain names, self, localhost, and all related domains.

**Example of CSC frame-ancestors from code:**
[image: CSC Policy Example]

**Error:** (Note the origin and function called are the same domain)
[image: Example Error from Console Log]

When this occurs, of course the calls back to M3/H5 are not completed.

If I run the same code **outside** of IOS, directly in M3/H5 Business Engine, no errors occur.  The dispatchEvent works, and M3 processes the transaction.

I've tried setting various IOS Grid settings, to no avail.  I've also opened a ticket with Infor, but they are still working on it.

**Grid Settings Tested**
[image: Grid Configuration Screen]

The actual code is dead simple, but for clarity I'll provide it too.  I've tried using postMessage as well as setting the targetOrigin parameter to '*'.

```js
        function callParentFunction(str) {
            if (str && str.length > 0)
            {
                //Errors indicate a mismatch in domain between the page containing the iframe and this page.

                console.log("callParentFunction:" + str);

                var event2M3 = new CustomEvent("adn2m3", { detail: str });
                event2M3.bubbles = true;
                event2M3.initCustomEvent("adn2m3", true, false, { detail: str });

                top.ccPaymentDiag.dispatchEvent(event2M3);
            }
        }

        function receiveMessage(event) {
            //console.log("receiveMessage");
            if (event && event.data) {
                console.log("call Event Origin: " + event.origin);
                callParentFunction(event.data);
            }
        }

        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
        } else if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage);
        }

        if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash.length > 1) {
            callParentFunction(window.location.hash.substring(1));
        }
```

At this point, I'm not sure how to proceed.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks;

Billy

Comment: Was there an issue with this question that caused it to get no comments or suggested answers, even with a bounty?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open this in a new window and get the result back.

It's the only way because this is a security issue. Frames are accesible from the parent page, so if you input a password there, the parent page can intercept it.

We've used a similar way to login using O365.